# derivative of the sum

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

My book says:

given
\begin{equation}
M_j\equiv e^{x_{jt}\beta-\alpha p_{jt}}+\xi_{jt}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s_{jt}=\frac{M_j}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{50}M_k}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{s_{jt}}}{\partial{p_{kt}}}=\frac{\frac{\partial M_j}{\partial p_{kt}}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{50}M_k}+\left(\frac{-M_j}{(1+\sum_{k=1}^{50}M_k)^2}\right)\left(\frac{\partial M_k}{\partial p_{kt}} \right)
\end{equation}
I dont't understand the last term in the derivative, because in my computations I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{s_{jt}}}{\partial{p_{kt}}}=\frac{\frac{\partial M_j}{\partial p_{kt}}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{50}M_k}+\left(\frac{-M_j}{(1+\sum_{k=1}^{50}M_k)^2}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{50}\frac{\partial M_k}{\partial p_{kt}} \right)
\end{equation}
where $\left(\frac{\partial M_k}{\partial p_{kt}} \right)$ is different from $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{50}\frac{\partial M_k}{\partial p_{kt}} \right)$ behause for a fixed $k$, for example $k=1$, in the first case I have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{s_{jt}}}{\partial{p_{1t}}}=...+...\left(\frac{\partial M_1}{\partial p_{1t}} \right)
\end{equation}
but in the second case I would get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{s_{jt}}}{\partial{p_{1t}}}=...+...\left(\frac{\partial M_1}{\partial p_{1t}}+\frac{\partial M_2}{\partial p_{2t}}+\frac{\partial M_3}{\partial p_{3t}}+\frac{\partial M_4}{\partial p_{4t}}+... + \frac{\partial M_{50}}{\partial p_{50t}}\right)
\end{equation}
My only doubt is that if $k$ is fixed, then the sum disappears and so I get the same result of the book .